# How to read values from response object?

Tags: javascript, object, response, ipfs

I am trying to read a value from a response object, but this

```
fetch("https://api.nft.storage/upload", options)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((response) => console.log(response))
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.value.cid);
            }
```

... doesn't work. Although my console shows the object being sent:

[image]

.. I get this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

1056 | .then((response) => response.json())
  1057 | .then((response) => console.log(response))
  1058 | .then((response) => {
> 1059 |   console.log(response.value.cid);
```

Answer (score 4):

`console.log()` doesn't return anything, so `response` in the next `.then()` is undefined. Just do both in the same function.

```
fetch("https://api.nft.storage/upload", options)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.value.cid);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar! Good having made this lesson ;)